# Reading asynchronously from stdin with Readline

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking at one of the examples in the O'Reilly book "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide" and was trying to make some changes.

This example, as it is written in the book works fine when you use input redirection:

```
node charfreq.js < input.txt
```

But I wanted to make a change so that the user can enter lines via the Win cmd line and when finished (ctrl+D), let the script continue.  To do this I tried to use `readline` instead of `process.stdin` but can't get the async to work.

**Here is the original code:**

```
async function histogramFromStdin() {
    process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8"); // Read Unicode strings, not bytes
    let histogram = new Histogram();
    for await (let chunk of process.stdin) {
        histogram.add(chunk);
    }

    return histogram;
}

// This one final line of code is the main body of the program.
// It makes a Histogram object from standard input, then prints the histogram.
histogramFromStdin().then(histogram => { console.log(histogram.toString()); });
```

**Here is what I tried so far:**

The issue here is that the call to `console.log(histogram.toString());` happens immediately, while histogram is still undefined.  Not sure where to await.

```
async function histogramFromStdin() {
    var readline = require('readline');
    process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
    let histogram = new Histogram();

    var rl = readline.createInterface({ input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout });
    rl.setPrompt('> ');
    rl.prompt();
    rl.on('line', function (chunk) { histogram.add(chunk); rl.prompt(); });
    rl.on('close', function () { console.log('Input has closed'); return histogram; });
}

// This one final line of code is the main body of the program.
// It makes a Histogram object from standard input, then prints the histogram.
histogramFromStdin().then(histogram => { console.log(histogram.toString()); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a mixed approach of `async/await` and `events`, as per docs: [Example: Read file stream line-by-Line: a mixed approach](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#example-read-file-stream-line-by-line)

Try this:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const {once} = require('events');

async function histogramFromStdin() {

    process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
    let histogram = new Histogram();
  
    try {
        
        const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout });

        rl.setPrompt('> ');
        rl.prompt();
        rl.on('line', function (chunk) { histogram.push(chunk); rl.prompt(); });

        await once(rl, 'close');

        console.log('Input has closed');

        return histogram;

    } catch (err) {

        console.error(err);
    }


}

// This one final line of code is the main body of the program.
// It makes a Histogram object from standard input, then prints the histogram.
histogramFromStdin().then(histogram => { console.log(histogram.toString()); })
```